# Как в WordPress c помошью метода WP_Query установить в запросе SQL параметр WHERE?

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне надо сделать выборку по автору на WordPress сайте из постов.

Этот запрос я делаю с помошью метода WP_Query.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type'   => 'market-reviews'
   'post_status' => 'array('publish')'
))
```

получается такой SQL запрос

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS web_posts.ID FROM web_posts WHERE 1=1 AND.....
```

Как мне в этом запросе указать параметр WHERE ? (сейчас он равен 1=1)

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/hook/posts_where оно?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по вашему вопросу и вот по [этой](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query) документации, наверное примерно так:

```
function modify_posts_where( $where ) {
    return $where . ' AND wp_posts.post_author = "Имя Автора"';
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'modify_posts_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type'   => 'market-reviews',
   'post_status' => 'array('publish')',
));
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'modify_posts_where' );
```

Comment: Ответ неправильный. У WP_Query нет такого аргумента. posts_where - это фильтр. В указанной вами ссылке написано, как его применять. Но совсем не так, как вы написали.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Изменил ответ, теперь правильно?

Comment: Да, можно и так. Убрал минус. Но в WP_Query есть аргумент author, и с его помощью можно сделать запрос по авторам без фильтра.

Comment: И значения авторов хранятся в виде целых чисел (int). Я вчера оба варианта попробовал.